# Sometimes, sleep mode asks for a PIN. Other times, it doesn't. Why?

Tags: laptop, sleep, windows-11, hybrid-sleep

After I got a new Windows 11 laptop, I noticed that when I close the lid, the computer can still charge USB devices and do other things. It's nice, as I don't think my old, pre-Windows 11 laptop could do that. However, when I open the laptop's lid, it will sometimes let me sign in without asking for a PIN, and other times it will require a PIN.

Why is this? Does Windows 11 (or at least my computer, anyway) have **two** sleep modes? Maybe one mode applies during a shorter period and the other during a longer period? What might be going on, and how might I predict each version?

Comment: Check your settings (user account) for the setting that requires (or does not require) Windows Hello . That setting affects this behaviour.  Also check in Personalization for checking for password on screen lock

Comment: Check in *Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options* if the drop-down under "Require sign-in" says "Never". If not, set it and reboot.

Comment: @John Ah, it looks like Windows Hello probably is the cause. One of the settings says, "When you've been away, when should Windows require you to sign in again?" I can choose "Never," "Every Time," or a number of minutes. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John said, it's probably something to do with Windows Hello.
You might have set facial-recognition that doesn't work when there's poor lighting conditions? ( Although it should use some special IR light or laser to measure your face... don't quote me on that, especially without knowing the laptop model )

Also, it might have something to do with your settings - might it be that closing the lid doesn't neceserily put the laptop to sleep, but it takes some time for the lock to happen?

Regarding your question: THERE ARE several sleep modes but you usually only use one of them.

Regarding USB charging - it is unrelated to Microsoft. There are usually some marked USB ports that supply power even when the computer is shut-down.